# Use A when IFNULL, else use + 1 letter

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-null

I have this mysql code:

`SELECT CHAR(ASCII(MAX(alfa)) + 1) FROM plaatregistratie_nr`

For selecting the next letter in the alphabet.

But when no letter exist I need to have the letter A so I have changed my query to:

`IFNULL(SELECT CHAR(ASCII(MAX(alfa)) + 1) FROM plaatregistratie_nr AS temp, 'A')`

But now getting error

`There is something wrong in the syntax used`

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: *But when no letter exist* then what value(s) may have `alfa` column?

Comment: Then I would like to have `A`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want `IFNULL()` within the `SELECT`, not around it:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CHAR(ASCII(MAX(alfa)) + 1), 'A') FROM plaatregistratie_nr
```

`COALESCE()` does the same thing as `ISNULL()`. I like it better because it is standard SQL.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now `0x01` is shown instead of `A`